# Add service reference (WCF, VS2008) to external service using WCF Proxy

Tags: proxy, reference, wcf

I use VS2008, .net 3.5.

There is an external Web Service (it is PHP implementation, but dont mind implementation -.net, java, php,...-).

In my project csproj, I want add Service Reference to WebService and I want use WCF.

When I add Service Reference in VS2008, WCF proxy is created.

Any best practices (patterns and practices) for add service reference (external service) ?

The WCF Proxy Generator (I think the same svcutil command) generates source code like this. Perhaps it will be interesting manages the code generated (ServiceContractAttribute Namespace="http://192.168.50.63/WebService" use IP address, and OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://devservername/webservice/SmoBridge.php/login" use servername).

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://192.168.50.63/WebService", ConfigurationName="ServiceEasyVista.WebServicePortType")]
public interface WebServicePortType {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://devservername/webservice/SmoBridge.php/login", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="return")]
    string login(string SESSION_ID, [System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="LOGIN")] string LOGIN1, string PASSWORD, string COMPANY_ACCOUNT);
```

Update:

the Erwyn’s recommendations about the correct closing of a faulted WCF Channel.
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx

Why does ClientBase Dispose need to throw on faulted state? (Or, what's the difference between close and abort?)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b95b91c7-d498-446c-b38f-ef132989c154/

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

http://www.sanity-free.com/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html

i think that one is sophisticated technique.

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

Comment: But as far as I know, using the "Add Web Reference" option does not use WCF.

Comment: Please read the full article, we also using the same technique in that case.

Comment: thx, another references best practices using .NET for any web service implementation (not only php, too .net WCF services, java...)

Comment: any comments for: Why does ClientBase Dispose need to throw on faulted state? (Or, what's the difference between close and abort?)  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b95b91c7-d498-446c-b38f-ef132989c154/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why there would be any particular best practices around adding a reference. Having said that, the "Refresh Reference" command in Visual Studio (right-click on an existing service reference) sometimes doesn't work too well, so it can be easier to use the `svcutil` command manually, and have a `.bat` file in your solution that updates the service reference (`svcutil` is what "Add Service Reference" is using behind the scenes).

Also, if the service you're referencing is returning an array, you can get WCF to automatically turn it into a generic list (or some other type) - this might make things easier.

Comment: VS  use WCF Proxy Generator (Custom Tool), perhaps it will be very interesting manages the code of WCF Proxy and others aspects.